# SIP dialog established via UDP - what is the transport AFTER a large SIP request has been sent via TCP?

Tags: sip

Given a SIP dialog (INVITE, 200 OK, ACK) has been established via UDP; And a large message gets sent that requires TCP as transport.
**What is the applied transport protocol after the large message has been sent for all other following (and normal sized) messages?**

*Does the protocol switch to TCP for all further request/responses or does it keep using the initially negotiated transport - UDP - for standard sized (NOT large) messages?*

---

What I found (based on RFC 3261):

> All SIP elements MUST implement UDP and TCP.  SIP elements MAY
> implement other protocols.
> *- from [rfc3261#18](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-18)*

> The ACK MUST be sent to the same address,
> port, and transport to which the original request was sent.
> *- from [rfc3261#18](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-18)*

Okay that says NOT all requests (especially ACK) are able to choose the transport independently.

> Making TCP mandatory for the UA is a substantial change from RFC
> 2543.  It has arisen out of the need to handle larger messages,
> which MUST use TCP, as discussed below.  Thus, even if an element
> never sends large messages, it may receive one and needs to be
> able to handle them.
> *- from [rfc3261#18](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-18)*

During an established dialog a UAS/UAC never knows if the need for a large message arises - switching from UDP to TCP is just fine (without any RE-INVITE that changes the transport in advance to the actual request).

> A 301 (Moved Permanently) or 302 (Moved Temporarily)    response may
> also give the same location and username that was    targeted by the
> initial request but specify additional transport    parameters such as
> a different server or multicast address to try, or    a change of SIP
> transport from UDP to TCP or vice versa.
> *- from [rfc3261#8.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-8.3)*

not really relevant - the UAS may want to change the transport suggested by the UAC; but that is based on the reaction onto some INVITE (or RE-INVITE) only

> The destination address,
> port, and transport for the CANCEL MUST be identical to those used to
> send the original request.
> *- from [rfc3261#9.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-9.1)*

Okay CANCEL (like ACK) also must NOT independently choose the transport.

> If a request is within 200 bytes of the path MTU, or if it is larger
> than 1300 bytes and the path MTU is unknown, the request MUST be sent
> using an RFC 2914 [43] congestion controlled transport protocol, such
> as TCP. If this causes a change in the transport protocol from the one
> indicated in the top Via, the value in the top Via MUST be changed.

That says if the SIP dialog was established via UDP, it has to be able to receive TCP requests also.

> For any port and interface
> that a server listens on for UDP, it MUST listen on that same port and
> interface for TCP.  This is because a message may need to be sent
> using TCP, rather than UDP, if it is too large.  As a result, the
> converse is not true.  A server need not listen for UDP on a
> particular address and port just because it is listening on that same
> address and port for TCP.  There may, of course, be other reasons why
> a server needs to listen for UDP on a particular address and port.

Okay that explains how switching from UDP to TCP works seamless. - And for the other direction it is just not required, but (I understand like: it still MAY work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both TCP and UDP are usable at that point and the transport layer is responsible for the choice.
SIP is transport independent, both are active at the same time.